# How to make a post API for mongodb with loopback

Tags: mongodb, strongloop, loopback

I am newbie with `mongodb` and `loopback`. I want to send and save data from my app to database. how can I do that?

**Update**
shops model:

```
{
  "shopname": "string",
  "tel": "string",
  "latlng": "string",
  "address": "string",
  "id": "string",
  "personId": "string"
}
```

CURL:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "shopname": "spring", \ 
   "tel": "12345678", \ 
   "latlng": "52.1106986,21.7768998", \ 
   "address": "05-319 Skwarne, Poland" \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3000/api/shops'
```

Now what should I write in `shops.js` to give an api for using in app to send data to database ?

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = function(Shops) {

    };
```

Comment: have you tried typing that into google? https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Connecting-to-MongoDB.html

Comment: @p.streef yes actually I've read this post,I found that I had to write functions for CRUD. but how and what to write I don't know clearly.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you should share that in your question? You should show effort on your part if you want people to help you. Share the code that you have tried and is not working and why it is not working.

Comment: I've update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have provided more info about the steps you have already done.
let me begin with the first step:

1. download and install mongodb on your server: [link](http://www.mongodb.com)
2. after running mongodb, add your desired database info to datasources.json file. e.g.

   ```
   {
       "db": {
       "name": "db",
       "connector": "memory"
       },
       "shopDB": {
       "host": "localhost",
       "port": 27017,
       "url": "mongodb://localhost:27017/shopDB",
       "database": "shopDB",
       "password": "",
       "name": "shopDB",
       "user": "",
       "connector": "mongodb"
       }
   }
   ```
3. add loopback-connector-mongodb to your project via npm.
4. now define your model(you can utilize loopback's user friendly command line interface to do so. call command "slc loopback:model" in your projects root folder)
5. after you finish the step 4, loopback will create 2files for you: shop.js and shop.json => these files are located in your projectFolder/common/models/ directory. note that it's a good practice to follow the loopback's convention in naming models and name your model in singular form(shop). (it uses the plural forms of the model names in other parts of the project). your shop.json should look like the below code:

   ```
   {
       "name": "shop",
       "plural": "shops",
       "base": "PersistedModel",
       "idInjection": true,
       "options": {
           "validateUpsert": true
       },
       "properties": {
           "shopname": {
               "type": "string",
               "required": true
           },
           "tel": {
               "type": "string",
               "required": true
           },
           "latlng": {
               "type": "string",
               "required": true
           },
           "address": {
               "type": "string"
           },
           "personId": {
               "type": "string",
               "required": true
           }
       },
       "validations": [],
       "relations": {},
       "acls": [],
       "methods": {}
   }
   ```
6. now you can post your shop json to http://localhost:3000/api/shops/ . note that our shop model inherits from PersistedModel base model and has some built-in functions to do crud operations. and if you want just create some shop instances in your db, you won't need to add anything to your shop.js file!

Comment: could you please help me how to write function to get data from URL? something like  http://localhost:3000/api/shops/shopname=cafedelmar&tel=123456&latlng=50.35;56.44 etc.....

Comment: @Reza Yeah, sure! But please publish a separate question, because it's a long story and can't be done through commenting:)